# Make chart using model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, charts

A have the following Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace GoOnWork.Models
{
    public class Skill
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime AddedOn { get; set; }

        public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }

        public int? DescriptionId { get; set; }

        public virtual Description Descriptions { get; set; }

        public int? LevelId { get; set; }

        public virtual Level Levels { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And I want to create chart with Level (xFields) and Description (yFields) from the Skill Model. The fields Description and Level are connected with other tables.
I have a chart view model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Helpers;

namespace GoOnWork.Models
{
    public class ChartViewModel
    {
        public Chart Chart { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I write a controller based on that view model.

```
public class ChartController : Controller
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        // GET: Chart
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new ChartViewModel
            {
                Chart = GetChart()
            };
            return View(model);
        }
        private Chart GetChart()
        {
            var user = User.Identity.GetUserName();
            var data = db.Skills.Where(x => x.User.UserName == user);
            return new Chart(600, 400, ChartTheme.Blue)
                .AddTitle("Skills")
                .AddLegend()
                .DataBindTable(data, "LevelName")
                .AddSeries(
                    "Default",
                    chartType: "bar",
                    xValue: data, xField: "LevelName",
                    yValues: data, yFields: "DescriptionName"
                    );
        }
    }
```

And the view of Index()

```
@model GoOnWork.Models.ChartViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Our Awesome Chart!</h2>
    @Model.Chart.Write(format: "png")
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to create chart with that fields.
Or how to modify the GetChart() function to work properly.
If somebody can help me, it would be better.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: I don't know how to write my GetChart() function to work properly with data from database.

Comment: Your just passing `IEnumerable<string>` to the `DataBindTable()` option (and `string` does not have properties `LevelName` and `DescriptionName`). Just remove the `.Select(y => y.Levels.LevelName)` from your query so you return `IEnumerable<Skill>`

Comment: Could you show me with code please.

Comment: `var data = db.Skills.Where(x => x.User.UserName == user);`

Comment: when I write .DataBindTable(IEnumerable<Skill>, " ") i get the error IEnumerable<skill> is a type but is used like a veriable

Comment: Why are you doing that? Its `.DataBindTable(data, "LevelName")` (i.e. just as your had it)

Comment: Ok I do this but my view don't work properly i write @model IEnumerable<ChartViewModels> but how to modify that row @Model.Chart.Write(format: "png") something with foreach or..

Comment: Why on earth are you changing the model to `@model IEnumerable<ChartViewModels>`? The ONLY change you need to make is to remove the `.Select(y => y.Levels.LevelName)` from your query as I stated previously i.e. it becomes `var data = db.Skills.Where(x => x.User.UserName == user);` (or maybe you need `.Select(y => y.Levels)` but impossible to tell because you have not shown all your models)

Comment: yes but if the View is same don't want to work and I get the error Chart Area Axes - The chart are contains incompatible chart types. For example, bar charts and column charts cannot exist in the same chart area.

Comment: You need to edit your question and explain exactly what properties of which model you actually want to create the chart for. I'm just guessing at the moment. But your problem is your `data` is currently only only a collection of `string` which cannot be bound to a chart.

Comment: I just want to create chart using fields from Skills model (xField Level, yField Description)

Comment: Which bit about _edit your question_ do you not understand?